# Как кликнуть по любому элементу и добавить класс?

Tags: jquery

Нужно кликнуть на любой элемент страницы и добавить ему класс .active. При втором нажатии на элемент нужно удалить класс. И если какой-то элемент уже имеет класс .active, то при клике на любой элемент класс .active добавлять не нужно.

Пытаюсь сделать так, но класс добавляется и элементу, и всем его родителям:

```
$("*").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("*").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```